# How to join 2 tables in Power BI with condition involving a 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables, Company, Address and C_detail. I need to count how many company with a certain C_ID from the C_detail table. But the relation existed are Company(CompanyID)=Address(CompanyID), Address(CountryID)=C_detail(CountryID). To be exact I need to translate this sql into Power BI.

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM Company a
JOIN Address b ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
WHERE b.CountryID IN ( SELECT CountryID from C_detail WHERE C_ID = '1')
```

How I join the tables with applying condition from different table?
Thanks and note that I am actually quite new with DAX so really appreciate a very clear explanation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create the relationships between those 3 tables in powerBI (set the filter to both directions):

```
Company to Address on CompanyID
Address to C_detail on CountryID
```

Then you can create a simple measure `COUNT(Company[CompanyID])` and use a slicer with the values of `C_ID`

If you don't want to or can't create the relationships, you can probably achieve a similar result with the following measure:

```
CompanyCount= 
VAR tbl =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Address',
                'Address'[CompanyID],
                "valid",
                    CALCULATE (
                        COUNTROWS ( 'Address' ),
                        TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Detail'[CountryID] ), 'Address'[CountryID] )
                    )
            ),
            [valid] > 0
        ),
        "CompanyID", 'Address'[CompanyID]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Company' ), TREATAS ( tbl, 'Company'[CompanyID] ) )
```

Comment: Really appreciate it! Apparently, `Address to C_detail on CountryID` is a many-to-many relationship, thus it does not become active. So when I did the slicer to filter, it didn't working.
Also, my result returns `(Blank)` when using your solution, whereas the sql will return a value to me.

Comment: Can you manipulate the tables? You can have a bridge table in between Address and C_detail to get rid of the many to many.

Comment: Hi @Joao Leal, sorry it took abit longer for me to learn and did the bridge. Yes, I created the bridge between Address and C_detail, called it Bridge table. If im not wrong, I should change the above measure, is it?

Comment: If you have the bridge table, then you should be able to just have a normal `COUNT(Company[CompanyID])`

Comment: Ah yes, it worked! Thank you so much mr. Well, there's one thing tho. The result varies with what my SQL returned. For example C_ID = 1, in SQL returns the count of 830while power BI exhibited 827. Where can I check why the values differs? If it's okay to ask you here.

Comment: Could you have duplicates in one of the tables? Try in your SQL doing `COUNT(DISTINCT a.CompanyID)....`

Comment: Yes indeed there're duplicates in the Address, thank you kind sir!